# Use GAE background thread to trigger SSE to multiple web clients

Tags: server-sent-events, google-app-engine

All,

I have completed the basic GAE "Guestbook" example which uses Google Cloud Endpoints and Google Cloud Messaging.  I can successfully add a note to the guestbook and have it appear on all registered devices.

I've also used the super simple Server Sent Event (SSE) mechanism to have a web page initiate an event source and then update itself as events are received.  But separate web pages appear to create their own distinct event sources (even if using the same URI to the event source) and thus get their own events at their own times.

The objective here is to create a bit of collaboration such that user actions can come from an android device or a web page and the effects the received action are then pushed to all connected users/devices/web pages.

I have assumed I will need a background module and that both Endpoints and 'normal' web pages / queries would channel the received user action to that background module.  I believe I can get that far.  Next, I need the background module to trigger a push notification to all interested parties.
I believe I can trigger a Google Could Messaging event to registered Android devices from that background module.

But it isn't clear to me how a background module can be the source of an SSE, or how the background module can best communicate with a foreground module that already is the source of an SSE.

I've looked at the Google Queue API, but I have a feeling I'm making something quite easy much more difficult than it needs to be.  If you were not going to 'poll' for changes from a web page... and you wanted to receive notifications from an SSE source when changes were made by other users, possibly using Android devices rather than a typical web page, and the deployed application is running on the Google Application Engine, what would you recommend?

Many thanks,

Randy

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, not really sure why you are using the background module but from what i understood you need to:

1. Your front end module receives an update
2. You retrieve a list of all devices receiving that update
3. Use the Queue service to send the update via GCM to every single device

**Why use queues?** because front end instances have a 1 min time limit per request and you'll need to queue work in order to go beyond that time to serve you (potentially) thousands of users.

Now, If you already have a backend instance (which does not have the 1min limit) you could just iterate over the list and send all messages on one request. I believe you have a 24 hr request limit so you should be OK. But in this scenario you don't have need for the front end module, you can just hit this server straight up.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.  I actually solved this by using Google Channels.  The Android application already has a means to register, receive notifications (via Google Cloud Messaging) and unregister.  Channels let the web application do the same thing.  You are notified with the Web application connects and disconnects.  On the server side, you can send a GCM notification to all Android applications and a Channel notification to all connected Web applications.  I don't know if this is ideal/preferred, but it is working for my needs thus far.